# Trying to use input values to fill out database connect parameter in php. giving this message

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
<body>
index.php
<form action="config.php" method="Post">
<table>
    <tr><td>DB Host: <input type="text" name="dbhost"></></tr>
    <tr><td>DB Name: <input type="text" name="dbname"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>DB pass: <input type="text" name="dbpass"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php 
config.php
$dbhost = $dbname = $dbpass = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $dbname = test_input($_POST["dbname"]);
    $dbpass = test_input($_POST["dbpass"]);

    $con = mysql_connect('$dbhost', '$dbname', '$dbpass');
    if (!$con) {
        echo "could not connect" . mysql_error();
    } else {
        echo "Processing...";
    }
}
    function test_input($data)![enter image description here][1]
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
  ?>
```

this is the error:

> could not connectphp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$con = mysql_connect('$dbhost', '$dbname', '$dbpass');
```

to

```
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbname, $dbpass);
```